# Delete all variables/objects from python environment using a function

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupyter Notebook and want to delete all the variables created after a certain point. I am able to do it using a for-loop looping through `dir()` and comparing it to the checkpoint that I create at the cell using `checkpoint = list(dir())`.

My goal is to clear the environment without losing the libraries that I import in the beginning (which is where I create my checkpoint). Anything I want to retain further, I can add to the checkpoint list and delete the rest.

The issue is, I don't want to write the same for-loop again whenever I want to clear the variables. As soon as I wrap that loop in a function, it stops working. There is no error; but there is no effect either.

Loop:

```
for i in list(dir()):
    if i not in checkpoint:
        exec('del {}'.format(i))
```

The same loop wrapped in a function:

```
def clear_variables():
    for i in list(dir()):
        if i not in checkpoint:
            exec('del {}'.format(i))
```

The loop works. The function doesn't.

Comment: How about creating functions for the various steps in your notebook? This has two benefits: one, variables are limited to the scope of the function and two, it'll make your code easier to refactor (and probably to reuse).

Comment: @OliverW. This notebook is me taking notes while going through an online course. Which means there are many variables that just hold data and are useless after a certain point in course is over. I wanted to do it in a single notebook instead of creating many and thought clearing the environment often would make things easier.

Comment: Exec is already a bad idea to begin with. Putting it in a function scope just runs del in the function, which if course does nothing to the globals.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yeah.. I figured that out just now. Also, dir() inside a function was returning the variables present inside the function itself. I have come up with a solution (it seems amateurish though). Could you tell me if I should post the solution or delete the question itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you are trying to update your global dictionary. You can't safely delete values from a dictionary while you're iterating over it, so you can make a copy of the keys first:

```
def clear_setpoint(keep, globals=globals()):
    keep = set(keep)
    for key in list(globals.keys()):
        if key not in keep:
            del globals[key]
```

If your only goal is to preserve imported modules, you don't even need to create a checkpoint:

```
from types import ModuleType, FunctionType

def clear_all(globals=globals()):
    for key in list(globals.keys()):
        value = globals[key]
        if not isinstance(value, (ModuleType, FunctionType, type)) or \
              (isinstance(value, FunctionType, type) and value.__module__ == globals['__name__'] and value.__name__ != 'clear_all'):
            del globals[key]
```

This version will automatically delete anything that is not a function, module or class. Classes and functions that are in the current module, based on their `__module__` attribute, are deleted as well. Other classes and functions are l And of course, you don't want to delete the function itself :)

kely to be imported, so are not deleted. This won't preserve imported constants, like if you do `from math import pi`. You can combine the two approaches to preserve imports like that.

Comment: Thanks. I got to the same solution. With a few more lines. This is concise. :)

Comment: Thank you. I think I can add another attribute to the function to contain a list of other objects I don't want deleted (like the example of pi) to handle exceptional cases.